# How to transform dataframe into "ColumnName1 | Value1 \r\n ColumnName2 | Value2 \r\n ColumnName3 | Value3" etc

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, export-to-csv

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of 11 columns and 1 row. I need the final output to go from:

```
Type ID From To
XYZ 999 Tony Andy
```

To:

```
Type|XYZ
ID|999
From|Tony
To|Andy
```

The result will the be exported to a txt file, which I believe I can manage.

Thank you!

Comment: Just transpose the DataFrame.  You probably want `df.T[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Just use Transpose:

```
m=df.transpose()
```

And then:

```
[str(list(a)[0])+'|'+str(list(a)[1]) for a in m.values]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip together the column names and value from the first row to pipe delimit them and then join the resulting list with a new line character to put everything on a separate line.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{"Type": "XYZ", "ID": 999, "From": "Tony", "To": "Andy"}])

print(
    "\n".join(["|".join([col, str(val)]) for col, val in zip(df.columns, df.iloc[0])])
)
```